# NHibernate ReferencesAny Fetching?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fetch

I have a class with a ReferencesAny map. For certain queries, I end up with an N+1 situation on that Any Map. Is there a way to use Fetch for an any map?

Here's what my linq query looks like (this works, but poor performance due to N+1):

```
return Session.Query<Path>().Where(p => {condition}).ToArray().Select(p => p.ContentsObject);
```

When I add a fetch into the mix:

```
return Session.Query<Path>().Where(p => {condition}).Fetch(p => p.ContentsObject).Select(p => p.ContentsObject);
```

The query blows up saying there is an invalid join.

Exception:

Invalid join: p.Page [.Fetch[wp.cms.DomainModel.Entity.Structure.PagePathMemento,wp.cms.DomainModel.Entity.Base.ILocatablePage](.Where[wp.cms.DomainModel.Entity.Structure.PagePathMemento](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[wp.cms.DomainModel.Entity.Structure.PagePathMemento], Quote((p, ) => (.Any[wp.cms.DomainModel.Entity.Users.UserSite](p.Site.Users, (u, ) => (Guid.op_Equality(u.User.Id, p1)), ))), ), Quote((p, ) => (p.Page)), )]
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.InvalidPathException: Invalid join: p.Page [.Fetch[wp.cms.DomainModel.Entity.Structure.PagePathMemento,wp.cms.DomainModel.Entity.Base.ILocatablePage](.Where[wp.cms.DomainModel.Entity.Structure.PagePathMemento](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[wp.cms.DomainModel.Entity.Structure.PagePathMemento], Quote((p, ) => (.Any[wp.cms.DomainModel.Entity.Users.UserSite](p.Site.Users, (u, ) => (Guid.op_Equality(u.User.Id, p1)), ))), ), Quote((p, ) => (p.Page)), )]

Comment: Show the full Exception + inner exceptions messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to eager load `any` mappings.

To avoid the N+1, set a reasonable `batch-size` on your entities (say, 20 or 50)

See [19.1.5 Using batch fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)

Comment: For some reason it's not letting me set batch size. When I try Session.SetBatchSize(50) it gives me the error: "No batch size was defined for the session factory, batching is disabled. Set adonet.batch_size = 1 to enable batching." I am using the NH GuidComb key generator and I have set the batch size property in my configuration. Any ideas?

Comment: That's not the batch size I'm referring to. See [5.1.3 class (13)](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-class)

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks much! This was a big help.